# Converting byte array to image in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimage

I am getting a byte array(I reckon) in `NSMutableArray's` object.The `NSMutableArray` i get is from `Xml` parsing from a service URL..Now I need to convert that byte array to `UIImage` ..Gone through google and found to convert to `NSData` and then `UIImage` but couldn't understand how..? How can I do it ?

My array looks like this :

```
(
{
        Name = "John";
        Image = "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD//gA7Q1JFQVRPUjogZ2QtanBlZyB2MS4wICh1c2luZyBJS
kcgSlBFRyB2NjIpLCBxdWFsaXR5ID0gODAK/9sAQwAGBAUGBQQGBgUGBwcGCAoQCgoJCQoUDg8MEBcUGBgXF
BYWGh0lHxobIxwWFiAsICMmJykqKRkfLTAtKDAlKCko/9sAQwEHBwcKCAoTCgoTKBoWGigoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgo/8AAEQgEKwZAAwEiAAIRAQMRAf/........
 //big byte array 
}
)
```

First of all I need to clear whether it is a byte array ?How can I extract image from this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your data is organized like this:

- The out-most data structure is a `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` (as you write).
- At index 0 (first element in array), there's an `NSDictionary` instance.
- In the dictionary, there are two key-value pairs. One has the key *Image* and a string as the value.
- The string value is binary data, encoded as Base64.
- The binary data is the image data.

So the get the image, you need to go this path:

```
NSMutableArray* array = ... // from XML
NSDictionary* dict = [array objectAtIndex: 0];
NSString* dataString = [dict objectForKey: @"Image"];
NSData* imageData = [dataString base64DecodedData];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
```

Note that the Base64 decoding is not part of iOS. But there are many implementations on the net for decoding a string into data. Just google it.

A Base64 implementation that looks good and simple can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64).

Comment: but example in the link u provided is not running in my mac(10.7.4) with xcode 4.1

Comment: docs there: Supported build target - iOS 5.1 / Mac OS 10.7 (Xcode 4.3, Apple LLVM compiler 3.0) -- you should update -- Id even say for any serious work, go to xcode  4.5.2+ (else, find a different implementation - as godo said: there are many! the dropbox sdk has a nice one too)

Comment: getting this error:target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.tool', but there's no such product type for the 'iphonesimulator' platform

Comment: You have probably added far too many files to your project. Just add the four files in the Base64 directory to your existing iPhone app project and import `NSString+Base64.h` into the class where you decode the Base64 data.